# Make element appear and follow mouse in div and disappear when mouse leave div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want my element to appear when the mouse enters a div, then follow the mouse and disappear once I leave the div.

I've mashed together the following code.

HTML:

```
<div id='box' class="box">
   <img id="image" src="download.jpeg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image {
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#image").css({
        left:e.pageX, 
        top:e.pageY
    });
});

$('.box').mouseenter(_=> {
    $('#image').show();
});

$('.box').mouseleave(_=> {
    $('#image').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rs_obi/hzkgb8fe/2/)

The intended functionality is inconsistent but seems to work if the mouse leaves the div quickly.

Comment: i want to get it to work as I described. I want the image to disappear as soon as the mouse leaves the parent element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `img` is inside of the box. When you hover and the image comes under your cursor, you're **ALWAYS** inside the box (since that's where the image is inside of the DOM structure).

So modifying your DOM as such:

```
<div id='box' class="box"></div>
<img id="image" src="https://i5.walmartimages.ca/images/Large/580/6_r/875806_R.jpg"/>
```

And then modify your CSS to include:

```
#image {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Should accomplish what you're looking for. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzkgb8fe/6/) with the modified code, too.

Comment: I assumed it worked by where the img is on the page! Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to do it without turning pointer events off? I'm doing a project where I want a different pointer event but my image flickers.